# Wix installer does not create folders or registry entries

Tags: wix

Well it was a working install to begin with. Then i believe some sort of incomplete uninstall happened.
Since then on more than two machines i am unable to use the installer.
It wont create any folders or registry entries .
It works on other machines.
I do not know which way to investigate this further.
Does a corrupt install of Wix have some sort of cache that i can clear to address this. I have now wasted two days for this and nothing.

I have tried checking registry entries for any evidence of corrupt install and still found nothing.

Comment: Create a verbose log by running this command-line: `msiexec -i YourSetup.msi -l*v LogFile.txt`. Search for "value 3" (localized) to find "hard" errors that caused a rollback. "Soft" errors (installer succeeds but does something wrong) are much harder to diagnose, have a look at feature and component states not far from the beginning of the log. Look for `Action: Null` to find components that you expect to install but didn't. Maybe a component condition is incorrect. Very hard to give concrete advise without further information.

Comment: Some links: [How To Read A Windows Installer Verbose Log](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/paulpaa/2010/02/05/how-to-read-a-windows-installer-verbose-log/) and [Windows Installer verbose log analyser](https://nextnextnextfinished.wordpress.com/2011/03/03/windows-installer-verbose-log-analyser-wilogutl-exe/)

Comment: Thank you. I was at wits end with this . Actually i just used this tool https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17588/fix-problems-that-block-programs-from-being-installed-or-removed and i see it working fine now. It was a corrupt install that was preventing this from creating its entries.